# Customize the ObjectHeader

Tags: sapui5

I have an `ObjectHeader` into a page. This is my properties:

```
condensed="true"
title="{model>/elements/idCodAnagr}"
intro="{model>/elements/idDescLangTable/elements/0/descrInLanguage}"
responsive="true"
backgroundDesign="Translucent"
numberUnit=""
number=""
```

`numberUnit` and `number` are not bind to the model and this is my result:
[image]

I have the space between `title` and `intro` and the tabs. 
How Can I reduce this space to expand the space for the tabs??

Answer (score 0):

Please add the code for the model definition. Using the binding in this way suggests that you have a model named 'model'.

```
... .setModel(oAppsModel, "model");
```

If you are just setting a model with no name remove "model>" from you binding.

Look at the binding as a folder structure. The first '/' is the root of the model. But only if you have one global model with no name. If you have named model you need to point which model you want to use for the binding. The way of writing this is "modelName>" ...

I hope this was usefull.

ps. Move you second issue into separate stackoverflow question. (1 issue per question ...)

Comment: `I have the space between title and intro and the tabs. How Can I reduce this space to expand the space for the tabs??` This is my question

Comment: Please share the implementation/usage of the object header you are using.
Btw ... if you ask me ... it will look and feel better if you put the title above the tabBar and spread the iconBar to 100% :)